# Updating Nextcloud 26 to Nextcloud 27 on an LXD container (high cpu after upgrade)

Tags: lxd

Has anyone tried updating from Nextcloud Hub 4 (26) to Nextcloud Hub 5 (27) on an LXD container. When I try this, the cpu is pegging like crazy filling up the syslog with a lot of output. Its the coolwsd process that seems to be eating the machine up.

LXD version 5.10
Ubuntu container running 20.04
I tried installing php 8.1

The syslog is filling up with error messages. I had to delete the container as it was growing too quickly.

I initially tried to do this by using the Nextcloud web based updater.
I then reverted back to Nextcloud Hub 4 and tried to run a do-release-upgrade and then upgrade to Hub 5 but I still get the cpu meters pegging.

Any thoughts on this?
Many thanks.